# onClick button: callback not executed

Tags: ajax, onclick, smalltalk, seaside

I'm wondering why the doRemoveObject method is not being executed when the button is clicked.

```
(html button)
  id: 'objectRemoveButton';
  bePush;
  onClick: (html scriptaculous request
      callback: [self doRemoveObject];
      confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?');
  with: 'Remove object'
```

Comment: Can you specify if there are any errors being logged to the console when clicking the button? (dev tools chrome/safari or firebug)

Comment: ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you did not include the prototype and/or scriptaculous libraries in the application.

Use the Seaside configure tool (http://localhost:8080/config/MyApplication) to add the 'PTDeploymentLibrary' & 'SUDeploymentLibrary' to your application (replace 'MyApplication' with the name of your application). The libraries setting can be found in the 'General' section of the configuration settings.

Alternatively, you can also programmaticaly add this to your application as follows:

```
|app |
app := self registerAsApplication: 'MyApplication'.
app addLibrary: PTDeploymentLibrary; addLibrary: SUDeploymentLibrary
```

Obviously, you can also use the PTDevelopmentLibrary.

ps: If you are developing a new application, consider using jQuery instead of Scriptaculous.